# Getting the Current Registered Organization Name (Company Name) in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have an old MFC application I need to rebuild.

It includes some code to read the current user's name and company. It accomplishes this by reading directly from the registry.

I really don't think this is a very reliable approach as future versions of Windows may change how and where some of this information is stored. So I would prefer to find an API call for this.

I managed to find the [GetUserName function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the user's name.

But is there any API to get the name of the registered user's company?

Comment: Related: [How do I read the 'company name' from Windows using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/272433/464709) (scroll down for non-registry-based answers).

Comment: Are you referring to `SystemParametersInfo`? That appears to return the OEM's company, and not the user's company or organization,

Comment: I was unsure about that one, but the [WMI one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/272603/464709) looks like what you want.

Comment: Looks pretty accurate on my machine, it is an empty string.

Comment: @HansPassant: Am I to understand that this is the expected result because you don't have any organization associated with your Windows installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function is based on code I found in the MSDN article "Example: Getting WMI Data from the Local Computer" found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

```
bool GetRegisteredUserInformation(std::wstring &registeredUser, std::wstring &organization)
{
    // Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------
    HRESULT hResult = ::CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------
    hResult = CoInitializeSecurity(
        nullptr, -1, nullptr, nullptr, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, nullptr, EOAC_NONE, nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        ::CoUninitialize();
        return false;
    }
    // Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------
    IWbemLocator *pLoc = nullptr;
    hResult = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *)&pLoc);
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        ::CoUninitialize();
        return false;
    }
    // Step 4: -----------------------------------------------------
    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method
    IWbemServices *pSvc = nullptr;
    // Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
    // the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
    // to make IWbemServices calls.
    hResult = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), nullptr, nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, &pSvc);
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        pLoc->Release();
        ::CoUninitialize();
        return false;
    }
    // Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------
    hResult = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pSvc, RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE, nullptr,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, nullptr, EOAC_NONE);
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        ::CoUninitialize();
        return false;
    }
    // Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----
    // For example, get the name of the operating system
    IEnumWbemClassObject *pEnumerator = nullptr;
    hResult = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"), bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY|WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        nullptr, &pEnumerator);
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        ::CoUninitialize();
        return false;
    }
    // Step 7: -------------------------------------------------
    // Get the data from the query in step 6 -------------------
    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;
    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        hResult = pEnumerator->Next(
            WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);
        if (0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }
        VARIANT vtProp;
        hResult = pclsObj->Get(L"RegisteredUser", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hResult) && VT_BSTR == vtProp.vt)
        {
            registeredUser = vtProp.bstrVal;
        }
        VariantClear(&vtProp);
        hResult = pclsObj->Get(L"Organization", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hResult) && VT_BSTR == vtProp.vt)
        {
            organization = vtProp.bstrVal;
        }
        VariantClear(&vtProp);
        pclsObj->Release();
    }
    // Cleanup
    // ========
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    ::CoUninitialize();
    if (!registeredUser.empty() || !organization.empty())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That should be called a "persistence API".  Look at how hard it is to obtain simple information and how many things can go wrong.  One would have to persevere to succeed!

Comment: @wallyk: It is not hard, it's just verbose (as is C in general). You are invited to use [`CCoInitialize`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/20/135841.aspx), [`_com_ptr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b.aspx), [`_variant_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x295h94e.aspx), and `_com_util::CheckError` to rewrite the code in C++. And see for yourself how little can actually go wrong. Of course, not knowing Windows programming doesn't help much.